# Need advice on domain modeling

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, devise, domain-driven-design

So, I wanted to get some advice on how to appropriately model a business logic domain.

Without going into too much NDA information, I'm trying to model a relatively large system that includes projects and people (nothing too scary so far). Right now I'm building it in Rails just to get something out the door quickly, but eventually I'm going to switch it over to an Ember.js/JSON app (not that that really matters for this question).

So the system has a couple different types of "people" -- there are "users" (people who can actually log in to the system), and "contacts" (information about people such as phone number, address, email, etc.). The only reason that these two are separated is they are logically different (contact info is not needed for login, and not every "contact" will need login info or should be ABLE to login). One question right off the bat is whether it makes sense to keep these two entities separate, or if I should just make one broad, flat object with all the fields to model both logins (and I'm thinking of all the fields that Devise adds here) and all the fields to do contact info.

Additionally, there are projects. Projects have people as "contacts" in different capacities; one project might have "Fred" as a lead or manager and "Diana" as a customer. It's possible (although unlikely) that another project might have "Diana" as a lead and "Fred" as another role. The point being that the roles that each contact plays in each project is fluid. There are a few roles that HAVE to be filled for a project to be valid (well, not necessarily valid, but active).

Finally, for a twist, the app is multi-tenanted. So the system itself has multiple "customers" (for lack of a better term) who have their OWN customers, and all of the (top-level) customer data must be kept strictly partitioned.

Right now, here's what I'm doing:

1. Darn near everything has a "customer_id" field on it, so that I can scope all requests by (my own) customers.
2. As mentioned above, "users" (people who can login) and "contacts" (human-useful information ABOUT people) are separate. One "user" must have one "contact", but "contacts" do not have to be associated with "users" (in Rails, I'm associating this by saying User belongs_to Contact). This is the first place where I'm not 100% sure I'm doing it right.
3. Projects and contacts are joined many-to-many (through a join table) so that a given project can have multiple contacts (and vice versa). The join table includes a "role" property so that I can say what role a contact plays in a project. This... works, but it makes the SQL very clunky (and I worry, slow). True, AREL manages most of the SQL for me, but still to get decent queries (and avoid N+1 issues), I have to do a lot of .joins/.includes calls, which to me sounds like a leaky abstraction.

So, I'll leave it at that, and end with what I started with: anyone got any advice or tips on how to properly model this system? I'll even take answers of "dude, it's a complex system but you're doing about the best you can do." :)

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question is too broad and you should split it into specific problems.  For point 3 are you using `has_many through:`?  I assume you are which means using lots of joins/includes is surely the best approach to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would tackle it...

First, diagrams are everything! Maybe you've done this or maybe not, but I always create a diagram showing all the different actors (in this case, the users, contacts, customers, and customers of customers) and draw their relationships.

Secondly, I would not separate users and contacts. What if a contact becomes a user? What if a user drops down to a contact? Etc, etc, these are all questions you must ask yourself--those "what-if" scenarios that, while they may not seem likely now, could crop up later. You'll want your system to be as flexible as possible if the use-case changes.

So, I would create a "user" table and give them a privilege column. Is this person a user or a contact? If the person is a user, make the contact info not required, but if they are a contact, then it is required but they can't log in. Also, you should probably have another option in case the person is both a user AND a contact.

I would then have a separate "relationships" table for the many-to-many use case of customers to customers-of-customers. Something like:

```
| ID | UserID | CustomerID |
-----------------------------
|  1 |      2 |          3 |
|  2 |      2 |          4 |
|  3 |      2 |          5 |
|  4 |      7 |          6 |
```

With the UserID being the parent customer's ID, and the CustomerID being the child customer's ID. You could then constrain who sees what.

For your projects question, same thing, I would make a separate model/table called ProjectRoles that has the project ID, the user ID, and the role name. It's a fine balance between making sure the table setup is solid/long-lasting and also loads fast with queries. I would rather it be right the first time!